# Angular dependency issue Windows to Linux

Tags: node.js, angular, angularjs, npm

I'm trying to host an Angular application for a customer, but I can't get it to run on Linux. The customer develops on Windows and it works for him. I am using NodeJS 19.

Error message when `npm install`:

```
npm notice
npm notice New minor version of npm available! 9.2.0 -> 9.3.1
npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v9.3.1>
npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@9.3.1` to update!
npm notice
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: @agm/core@3.0.0-beta.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@14.2.12
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"^14.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"^14.0.0 || ^15.0.0" from @angular/cdk@14.2.7
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/cdk
npm ERR!     @angular/cdk@"^14.2.4" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @angular/cdk@"14.2.7" from @angular/material@14.2.7
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/material
npm ERR!       @angular/material@"^14.2.4" from the root project
npm ERR!       1 more (@angular/material-moment-adapter)
npm ERR!   5 more (@angular/forms, @angular/material, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^9.1.0 || ^10.0.0" from @agm/core@3.0.0-beta.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@agm/core
npm ERR!   @agm/core@"^3.0.0-beta.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/common@10.2.5
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@"^9.1.0 || ^10.0.0" from @agm/core@3.0.0-beta.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@agm/core
npm ERR!     @agm/core@"^3.0.0-beta.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "web-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^3.0.0-beta.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^14.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.2.10",
    "@angular/material": "^14.2.4",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^14.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^14.2.10",
    "@manekinekko/angular-web-bluetooth": "^11.2.2",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.39.13",
    "@types/maplibre-gl": "^1.14.0",
    "@types/web-bluetooth": "^0.0.16",
    "bootstrap": "^3.4.1",
    "maplibre-gl": "^1.15.3",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.2.2",
    "@angular/cli": "~14.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.2.0",
    "@types/geojson": "^7946.0.10",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.3.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.7.2"
  }
}
```

I have already tried `--force` and `--legacy-peer-deps` but it still doesn't work.

Comment: `Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/common@10.2.5` you have conflicting versions. Delete your node modules and run `npm install` again

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things here.

First one of the packages you're using doesn't like the version of Angular you're using.

@agm/core@3.0.0-beta.0

This says that @agm/core@3.0.0-beta.0  is made for angular 9-10 and you're running 14.

```
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^9.1.0 || ^10.0.0" from @agm/core@3.0.0-beta.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@agm/core
npm ERR!   @agm/core@"^3.0.0-beta.0" from the root project
```

If you MUST use this version of @agm/core@3.0.0-beta.0 then you can run:

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```

But this is not best practice. It's better to look for a version that works with your Angular version. A quick look at that package (npm view @agm/core versions --json) shows me that you have the latest version, since it's dependency is Angular 9-10 you might want to look for a replacement library that works with your version of Angular.

Second, you are using a development version of node, meaning that 19 is the latest but not considered stable by node.js- odd numbers for development, even numbers for production, current stable version is 18.13.0:
https://nodejs.org/en/download/

If you want to use multiple versions of node, you can use nvm (Node version manager)

Your version of node.js needs to match the installation version of node.js - so the Windows machine and the Linux machine need to both have the same version of node.js - that might be why it works in one place and not the other.